# Is there a way to pass a value from one swift script to another swift script?

Tags: swift, scripting

I am hoping to be able to reuse some functions in several different scripts. Is there any way I can create a like commonFunctions.swift file and access those functions from other swift scripts?

Comment: What do you mean by "Swift Script?" Swift is a compiled language. You create a project that contains one or more source files and then build them into an application or command line tool. It is certainly possible to share classes, structures, global functions, and other things across multiple source files. You can also use a package manager like the Swift Package manager, CocoaPods, Brew, or various others to share packages of code between your projects.

Comment: This swift script will be run outside of the Xcode project level. It will be run to query over files in a directory.

Comment: You need to use a package to bundle the source files you need, go to [this page](https://www.swift.org/getting-started/) on swift.org and scroll down to the section “Package Manager”.

Comment: Your question is too vague to be anserable. Are these "scripts" separate programs? Are they different frameworks/libraries/source files that will combined into a single program? You need to clarify your question.

Comment: Let’s say there is a folder called dogs and inside the folder there is a dog.swift file. Inside the dog folder there are also other folder that the dog.swift file will be querying. 

I want a file in the same directory that has reusable functions such as writing to a file or creating a file.